# Adding data on excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data like this:

[image]

I want to add tests from Column N to X bu using a userform.
in the userform i have a combobox populated like this:
[image]
For example if add test D for the 1st time it should be Added on column 3, if I add a 2nd test D it should be Added on column 4... If I add test A for the 1time it should be Added on column 1, the seconde test A should be Added on column 2.... (like in the 1st pic)
Each time the name of persons and service is added automatically.
I am trying to set a condition to be able to get what I want I've writen this code:

```
' code for the button on my worksheet
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'-------------Populate the comobox of persons and tests
Dim ws_Liste_Pers As Worksheet
Set ws_Liste_Pers = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("service ")
Fin_Liste_Pers = ws_Liste_Pers.Range("A65530").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Fin_Liste_Pers
    UserForm_SDE.ComboBox_Demandeur.AddItem ws_Liste_Pers.Range("A" & i)
  
Next i

Dim ws_tech_essais As Worksheet
Set ws_tech_essais = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(" tech essais")
Fin_Liste_tech_essais = ws_tech_essais.Range("A65530").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Fin_Liste_tech_essais
    UserForm_SDE.ComboBox_Tech_Essai.AddItem ws_tech_essais.Range("A" & i)
Next
  

UserForm_SDE.Show
End Sub



'Code for the userfom to add the data 
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TPers = Feuil2.[A2].Resize(Feuil2.[A1000000].End(xlUp).Row - 1, 2).Value
    ReDim TPlaces(0 To ComboBox_Tech_Essai.ListCount - 1)
    
    Dim LP As Long, LS As Long, CS As Long
       LP = ComboBox_Demandeur.ListIndex + 1
    '   If LP = 0 Then Exit Sub
    '   If Not ComboBox_Tech_Essai.MatchFound Then Exit Sub
       CS = TPlaces(ComboBox_Tech_Essai.ListIndex) + 1: If CS < 14 Then CS = 14
       TPlaces(ComboBox_Tech_Essai.ListIndex) = CS
       On Error Resume Next
       LS = WorksheetFunction.Match(TPers(LP, 3), Feuil2.[A:A], 0)
       If Err Then LS = 0
       On Error GoTo 0
       If LS > 0 Then If Not IsEmpty(Feuil2.Cells(LS, CS).Value) Then LS = 0
       If LS = 0 Then
          LS = Feuil1.[A1000000].End(xlUp).Row + 1
         
          Feuil1.Cells(LS, 1) = TPers(LP, 1)
    '      Feuil1.Cells(LS, 2) = TPers(LP, 2)
          End If
       Feuil1.Cells(LS, CS) = ComboBox_Tech_Essai.Value
    
    Unload Me
    End Sub
```

The problem is that this code is adding the tests only on column N.
Can anyone help me to find teh pb. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the next code, please. In order to properly work, **it needs the strings matching the test numbers (from the sheet) to be exactly formatted like in the combo box** I mean, like "001", "002" .... I did not observe how you loaded the combo, but it would be necessary to do the same for the range in H:H column. The best text format is obtained by selecting the column in discussion and then: `Data tab -> Text to Columns... -> Next -> Next`, then check 'Text' in 'Column data format' and press 'Finish':

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, rngTNo As Range, rngCol As Range, iRow As Long, i As Long
   Dim ComboBox_No As MSForms.ComboBox, ComboBox_Test As MSForms.ComboBox
   
   'use in the next row your real combo boxes. I named mine ComboBox_No, respectively, ComboBox_Test
   'You will use something like: Me.ComboBox_Tech_Essai, Me.ComboBox_Demandeur...
   Set ComboBox_No = frmTest.ComboBox_No: Set ComboBox_Test = frmTest.ComboBox_Test
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'Feuil2
   Set rngTNo = sh.Range("H7:H" & sh.Range("H" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row) 'Test numbers range
   If rngTNo.cells.count < 1 Then MsgBox _
            "There necessary Test numbers range is missing...": Exit Sub
   If rngTNo.NumberFormat <> "@" Then MsgBox _
            "The Test numbers range must be formatted as text!": Exit Sub
    
   iRow = rngTNo.Find(ComboBox_No.Value).Row 'row to be used for dropping the test
   For i = 14 To 25
       Set rngCol = sh.Range(sh.cells(7, i), sh.cells(sh.cells(Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).Row, i))
       If rngCol.Find(ComboBox_Test.Value) Is Nothing Then
            If sh.cells(iRow, i).Value = "" Then
                sh.cells(iRow, i).Value = ComboBox_Test.Value: Exit For
            End If
       End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, it gives exactly what I wanted. Please what do you suggest for me to learn coding with VBA any websites or books, because Im Always lost and I really need it.

Comment: @FaruSZ: Well, I cannot guide you from this point of view.. I learned it without any course or tutorial. I saw the code, tested, try understanding and then improving it. But, to be a good programmer, knowing the programming language is necessary, but not enough. You must cultivate your imagination! You must perfectly understand **what** is to be done, then **imagine a way to do it**. What I would recommend you, no offence, the first thing you must learn is **asking questions**. If you will not be able to perfectly explain what is to be done, you will never succeed to be a good programmer...

Comment: @FaruSZ: First step now would be to try perfectly understanding the above code. If you do not understand something, do not hesitate to ask! Then, try to modify something in it, in order to be sure that you understood it. And now I will remind you (again) our habit here: When somebody answer your question and you are satisfied, you should vote the code up, and more important to check the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: yes you're right, thank you for your good advises, I am trying to learn how to code by testing codes, edditing them and try to understand how they  work. I have strated doing this for 3 months but it's not enough yet I am still a begginer.

Comment: Okay if I dont understand anything I'll come back to you, I really appreacite your efforts. Sometimes I hesitate to ask questions because I dont have anyone to help me, I lose hours trying to find the answers sometimes days, when I post my pb here you do take your time to solve it. Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line of code:

```
CS = TPlaces(ComboBox_Tech_Essai.ListIndex) + 1: If CS < 14 Then CS = 14
```

Which is setting the column index you use near the end of your sub:

```
Feuil1.Cells(LS, CS) = ComboBox_Tech_Essai.Value
```

14 = N so with the statement `If CS < 14 Then CS = 14` the code will never populate a column before N.

Answer (score 0):

@FaneDuru
To do simple look at this picture:
[image]
I want to choose the test number from a combobox, and then add the test by chosing it from a combox like this :
[image]

when adding a new test the code should look for the test N° on column H and the the name of the chosen test from the combobox, if the test exsits in column N it should be adde in M, if we select the same test the code must add it on the column O ...
column
in the same column I must not have the same test Name, look at the 1st picture  for test A in green. ( I have selcted 001 from the combobox so tets A was Added on column N, a second test A N°001 its Added in column M)
For test B in yellow you see that the first value is in column P, because I have selected tets N° OO1, for the 2nd test B I have choosen test Number 002 from the combobox so it was added on column N

Comment: Please, clarify the next issue: If test number will be "007", test to be filled is "A", cell "N13"  is empty, but on cells "N8", "A" exists, where will be it placed? In "N13" or in "O13"?

Comment: it will be placed on O13

Comment: And "N13" remains empty. Empty **forever**, or if another selected test does not exist in N:N should it be placed in "N13"?

Comment: if another selected test does not exist in N:N it should be placed in "N13"

Comment: OK. I do not have time right now to prepare a piece of code, but in less then an hour I hope to have...